# How to officially auto size a container to its content when elements are absolutely positioned?

Tags: css

What is the official way to auto size a container div to it's contents?

I want the "BorderContainer1056" to size to it's contents:

```css
#BorderContainer1056 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 39px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 240px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 1);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #696969;
  border-radius: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#VGroup1061 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: left;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="BorderContainer1056">
  <div id="VGroup1061">
    <span id="Label1063">Vertical Group in Container</span>
    <span id="Label1064">Apple</span>
    <span id="Label1065">Orange</span>
    <span id="Label1066">Banana</span>
    <span id="Label1067">Grape</span>
    <span id="Label1068">Cherry</span>
    <span id="Label1069">Mango</span>
    <span id="Label1070">Kiwi</span>
    <span id="Label1071">Pineapple</span>
    <span id="Label1072">Strawberry</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why can't their be a property on the container telling it to size to it's content?

Here is the running example, https://jsfiddle.net/bj354bcq/.

Specific information from a browser manufacturer or w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss would be helpful.

The post linked to as a duplicate has a lot of "This is how I did it answers." They don't reference any official documentation or the W3 behaviors references. Those answer do not answer my question and do not work with the code above. So I'm asking the browser manufacturers or developers that know what an official method is.

**UPDATE 2020:**
Please reopen. I sort of figured out a way to handle it. Taken into account,

[If all child elements of a container are absolutely positioned, the parent’s height will collapse to zero.](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Summary)

We can specify one element as the sizing element. This can be an element that grows or is the farthest bottom edge in the container. Set this element to position relative and remove the height on the container (and possibly also add position relative to the container. The container will then size, height wise, to the sizing element.

If you have other elements above or below in the DOM hierarchy you can do the same with those. Remove the height on the container, position it as relative and "stack" these elements.

I'll try to post an update with more code and instructions here. I can't add as an answer because someone closed this question. I've updated the question title in hopes it makes it clearer.

**NOTE**: Stack Overflow just awarded this question as notable!
[image]

Comment: There is no "official way". Who would officiate such a thing?

Comment: I would recommend a property on the container such as `height:content`. In other layout languages such as Java they have an `autosize` and `sizetocontent` values on the container that do just this. The W3C is the official body that adds and recommends official improvements and standards.

Comment: Also, internally, Firefox, Chrome and others have layout rules and one of those rules is to set the size of the container to the size of it's content. It should have a condition that determines when and how the container is sized. I'm wondering if they have a property and value that turn this auto sizing on and if they would be kind enough to share it.

Comment: Stop telling us that this is not a duplicate, and show us how your question differs from any of the others.

Comment: I already mentioned it's asking for a specific official property or value. It then gives an example that can be tested against. That question gives random suggestions. Nothing was mentioned as being an official method to get the desired results.

Comment: So, why would you assume the other answers are *non-official*? What do you even think "official" means in this context?

Comment: Because they don't work on the example above and because they don't link to official documentation on mozilla com or the W3C.

Comment: That isn't how the site works. You don't get to brand the existing answers "unofficial" because you don't like them. You need to modify your question to substantially disambiguate it from existing questions in order for it to be reopened.

Comment: Those are hearsay answers. They are a list of "here's what worked for me". This is not an official, here's how to do it and here's the documentation.

Comment: Place a bounty on the other question if you need better answers.

Comment: This is a separate question. That's "how do you auto size, any method is ok" my question is "How do you officially auto size a div to it's content". It's different.

Comment: This site https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss has the official guidelines for how to size, position and style HTML. They usually have a description how to get a specific behavior. Unfortunately, I've searched their site and can't find it. A developer at Firefox or Chrome or an advanced user will know the answer to this.

Comment: The post you linked to is not a duplicate of this post. Please reopen.

Comment: Are we talking about absolute positioned elements? .. If we are, they do size to their content (if not their immediate children also is positioned absolute), just add `height: auto`, and of course remove `overflow: auto`. Here is a fiddle showing that: https://jsfiddle.net/n8pL9m4v/1/

Comment: If we talk about element in general, and size to content, more or less all elements are sized by their content if they don' have a given size or a property set, blocking them to do so, and some does it both horizontally and vertically, some in just one direction. It is all very well explained here, officially: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display

Comment: So, to auto size an element is more to it than just set a property. If you like, I can post these comments as an answer, if they answer your question.

Comment: @LGSon I'm talking about absolutely positioned elements. In the jsfiddle example you set the position to relative. Can you show an example without changing the position of the contents?

Comment: I was hoping for an answer but I'm not ready to accept one yet. @LGSon suggestion is different than the code in the jsfiddle so I'm not sure what's going on with that. The answer you provided sets the width instead of the height. If that's how you do it and you can't set the width than I'm not sure if auto size is possible. If you have to set the width to auto size the height and that width cannot be explicit then I'm not sure if either answer fits the definition. It may be the right answer but I'd like to wait or research more since it does not solve all the problems in the example code.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts When an element is set to `position: absolute` it is take out of flow, which means it renders as if it were alone. A nested does the same, so what happens here is, your first element, `BorderContainer1056`, has no flowed content so its height is 0. The nested element though, will size to its content, as it has flowed content. To be able to see that, the `overflow: auto;` needs to be removed, as this property expects a height or else it will collapse the elements height showing nothing but flowed content. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n8pL9m4v/3/

Comment: So the real answer to your question is, it depends on which display and positioning type you use, where `height: fit-content` is one, `height: auto` is another, and they can't be combined in any way wanted, as one can take out the other. And to make it even more complicated, showed in your case, there are more properties that can affect it, such as `overflow: auto`.

Comment: So it sounds like it is possible to auto size through a combination of styles but with absolutely positioned elements it is not possible to auto size the container? Yes, go ahead and post an answer, no matter what the answer is, even if it's complicated.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts as LGSon has stated, nested absolutes are a nasty business. Removing `absolute` on `#VGroup1061` and changing `#BorderContainer1056` width implicitly will work.

Comment: I'm going to err on the side of caution and close this as unclear rather than too broad. Because if we're to take your question literally, then your question *is* too broad, because you'd have to account for every single possible layout configuration which, with CSS3, is a perpetually expandable set of scenarios. And even if we only consider your specific scenario, then the answer to your literal question is "there is an official way - *and you're looking at it right now*". But I strongly suspect that is not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Because if it was, then you wouldn't be asking how to get that container to auto-size to its contents, because that's exactly what it's doing right now - there's just *nothing* for the container to accommodate because its only child is absposed and therefore removed from its flow. More likely, you just want the child to be taken into account when sizing the container, to which the answer is simple: remove the position: absolute declaration from the child.

Comment: Or if you want the child to be taken into account *even as it's absposed* (again, I can't tell, because you've framed your question as something else altogether), then the answer is that you can't, no matter how the container and content are laid out or what funky new CSS3 properties you use, because to do so would be going against the very idea of absolute positioning.

Comment: @boltclock why don't you add that as an answer instead of putting the question on hold?

Comment: First meager marked this as a duplicate, then finally, it was marked as not a duplicate and now you are putting it on hold because you don't understand it. Please remove the hold.

Comment: @BoltClock being that it's absolutely positioned shouldn't mean it should be taken out of the flow. if it does then the top and left properties of the child content should apply to the document container not the parent. but it doesn't. the top and left of child absposed content are relative to the parent container. thus it can be inferred that the parent should or can be sized to fit the content.

Comment: @BoltClock and if you do use position:relative the container is NOT sized correctly to the content if the content has top or left positions other than zero. see https://jsfiddle.net/bj354bcq/1/. the only change is the content has position relative instead of absolute and overflow is removed. as you can see the container is not correctly sized to the content. please remove the hold.

Comment: @BoltClock the answer is *apparently* that it's not possible using absolute positioned content and with relative positioned content it's broken and/or not implemented correctly yet or at all.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts If you read the "Value" section at this link, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position, it will explain exactly how positioned elements relates and positions. It will answer your comment's questions/statements, that nothing is broken or implemented wrong, it all work how it's supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

To summarize:

- `#VGroup1061`:

> [No `position:absolute`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Summary)

- `#BorderContainer1056`

> No explicit width

Don't have a link for the second point yet, but it makes sense if you have a child at 120px and you want the parent to shrink at the size of content, then the width can't be set to 240px. Alternatives are: max-width, auto✲, etc.

Change your `#VGroup1061` by removing `position:absolute` or change it to `position: static` or even `position:relative`. Positioning children elements in a positioned parent at a collapsed height of 0, and in your case where you want the parent shrinkwrapped on the child, it wouldn't be useful but actually detrimental.

This [article](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning) is an official take on the subject from W3.

> [If all child elements of a container are absolutely positioned, the parent’s height will collapse to zero.](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Summary)

After adding `position:absolute` back to the Snippet (because it's irritating and made no difference to demonstrate what I intended to demonstrate), and making the child element `position:static` or `relative` and **removing the fixed width** of `#BorderContainer1056` (the original "controlled" subject)  makes it behave as OP wanted it to in the first place.

I believe the placement of the following rulesets✎ should go at the top of the stylesheet as well:

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Placing powerful resets at the bottom of a stylesheet or block will undo everything (i.e. margins, padding, etc.) preceding it due to inheritance.

<del>I just remembered that `display:table-cell` can do what you want as well, see updated Snippet, in particular `#BorderContainer3056`.</del> `display: table-cell` works only if `#BorderContainer3056` doesn't have an explicit width. Perhaps it could work if wrapped in another container with:

```
display:table;
table-layout: fixed;
```

In the Snippet below, there are <del>2</del> 5 identical sets of a `<section>`, a `<div>`, and 10 `<span>`s.

1. Both `<section>`s have a pink background and green border.
2. Both `<section>`'s contents:

   - Contains a `<div>` which contains...
   - ...10 `<span>`s
3. The `<section>`'s contents have a purple background and yellow border.

Notice the second set `<section>`'s green border wraps perfectly around it's content. This is possible by using the [`fit-content`](http://thenewcode.com/?search=fit-content) property or [`min-content`](http://thenewcode.com/?search=min-content)

```
#BorderContainer2056 {
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

- `fit-content` can be found under [CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3 in the W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/).
- With the appropriate vendor prefix (see previous example), it can be used by Firefox and Chrome, but IE and Edge is a no go (no surprise there of course).

> [Note: This is called the “shrink-to-fit” width in CSS2.1§10.3.5 and CSS Multi-column Layout § 3.4.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#fit-content-size)

```
#BorderContainer4056 {
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: min-content;
}
```

- `min-content` is referenced in the same area as `fit-content`
- As LGSon pointed out it is experimental, for the last 10 years, but I'm sure he'll find a solution more suitable and official.

✎ The rulesets above are my version and varies with your original ruleset, but nevertheless it still applies.

✲ `auto` attributed to @LGSon's comments see `##BorderContainer5056` in Snippet.

#### SNIPPET

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(225, 0, 0, .4);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: green;
  text-align: right;
  width: 240px;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ded;
}
span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .4);
  border: 1px solid gold;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
}
#BorderContainer2056 {
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
/* Separated for demo purposes */

#BorderContainer2056 {
  top: 250px;
}
#BorderContainer3056 {
  display: table-cell;
}
/* Separated for demo purposes */

#BorderContainer3056 {
  top: 500px;
}
#BorderContainer4056 {
  position: relative;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: min-content;
}

/* Separated for demo purposes */

#BorderContainer4056 {
  top: 750px;
}
#BorderContainer5056 {
  width:auto;
}
/* Separated for demo purposes */

#BorderContainer5056 {
  top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<section id="BorderContainer1056">
  BG1056
  <div id="VGroup1061">
    <span id="Label1063">Vertical Group in Container</span>
    <span id="Label1064">Apple</span>
    <span id="Label1065">Orange</span>
    <span id="Label1066">Banana</span>
    <span id="Label1067">Grape</span>
    <span id="Label1068">Cherry</span>
    <span id="Label1069">Mango</span>
    <span id="Label1070">Kiwi</span>
    <span id="Label1071">Pineapple</span>
    <span id="Label1072">Strawberry</span>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="BorderContainer2056">
  BG2056
  <div id="VGroup2061">
    <span id="Label2063">Vertical Group in Container</span>
    <span id="Label2064">Apple</span>
    <span id="Label2065">Orange</span>
    <span id="Label2066">Banana</span>
    <span id="Label2067">Grape</span>
    <span id="Label2068">Cherry</span>
    <span id="Label2069">Mango</span>
    <span id="Label2070">Kiwi</span>
    <span id="Label2071">Pineapple</span>
    <span id="Label2072">Strawberry</span>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="BorderContainer3056">
  BG3056
  <div id="VGroup3061">
    <span id="Label3063">Vertical Group in Container</span>
    <span id="Label3064">Apple</span>
    <span id="Label2065">Orange</span>
    <span id="Label3066">Banana</span>
    <span id="Label3067">Grape</span>
    <span id="Label3068">Cherry</span>
    <span id="Label3069">Mango</span>
    <span id="Label3070">Kiwi</span>
    <span id="Label3071">Pineapple</span>
    <span id="Label3072">Strawberry</span>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="BorderContainer4056">
  BG4056
  <div id="VGroup4061">
    <span id="Label4063">Vertical Group in Container</span>
    <span id="Label4064">Apple</span>
    <span id="Label4065">Orange</span>
    <span id="Label4066">Banana</span>
    <span id="Label4067">Grape</span>
    <span id="Label4068">Cherry</span>
    <span id="Label4069">Mango</span>
    <span id="Label4070">Kiwi</span>
    <span id="Label4071">Pineapple</span>
    <span id="Label4072">Strawberry</span>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="BorderContainer5056">
  BG5056
  <div id="VGroup5061">
    <span id="Label5063">Vertical Group in Container</span>
    <span id="Label5064">Apple</span>
    <span id="Label5065">Orange</span>
    <span id="Label5066">Banana</span>
    <span id="Label5067">Grape</span>
    <span id="Label5068">Cherry</span>
    <span id="Label5069">Mango</span>
    <span id="Label5070">Kiwi</span>
    <span id="Label5071">Pineapple</span>
    <span id="Label5072">Strawberry</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think it is important to point out that `fit-content` is experimental and should be avoided in production environment. Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

Answer (score 2):

> What is the official way to auto size a container `div` to it's contents?

It depends among others on which display property, `block, inline-block, inline, table-cell, etc.`, and position property, `static, relative, absolute, etc.`, is used.

Src: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display

> Why can't their be a property on the container telling it to size to it's content?

There is, though it is not one property, it is several, `width/height, max-width/height, min-width/height, etc.`, so we can control exactly *how* it should size itself using property values like `auto, percent, px, vh, vw, etc.`.

Src: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties#Box_Size

At [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) and [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/) one can read more about upcoming sizing features like `fill, available, min/max/fit-content, etc.`, some more rolled out, some less.

---

Based on your question's sample (and comment), here is a few samples for absolute positioned `div`.

Element with `position: absolute` do size itself to its content, if it has normal flowed content,

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>Hi there, ...<br>...how are you? </div>
```

but in your case, it's non normal flowed content, a second absolute positioned element, which has normal flowed content. The inner element will act as the above, and size itself to its content, and the outer will too actually, though its size is 0.

This happens because absolute positioned elements is taken out of flow and as such they render as if they where alone on a web page, so here the outer "don't know" there is an inner, hence doesn't become visible.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}
.outer {
  background: lightblue;
}
.inner {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Hi there, ...<br>...how are you? </div>
</div>
```

Why your sample doesn't show anything is because you used `overflow:auto`, which expects a height or else it will collapse the elements height and only grow with normal flowed content.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}
.outer {
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
}
.inner {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Hi there, ...<br>...how are you? </div>  
</div>

<hr>

<div class="outer">
  Normal flowed content
  <div class="inner">Hi there, ...<br>...how are you? </div>  
</div>
```